# allowsSelectionDuringEditing property for NSTableView

Tags: nstableview

Application I'm trying to develop is heavily built around being able to have editable TableViews. I'm beginning to conclude that most if not all of my problems stem from the fact that I do not see allowsSelectionDuringEditing available for NSTableView as it is for UITableView.

First, would like to get insight into why.

Second, how do I go about implementing one in my NSTableView class?

Finally, I have a `NSSegmentedControl` in one of my columns. So I need to implement `allowSelectiongWhenFocused` property somewhere, because while I have focus on the button and allowing user to use <- and -> with spacebar to select switch(es), I don't want mouse / keyboard from changing the selected row.

As an aside, while I now know how to write custom UI classes and hook them into Interface Builder, I'm struggling on when/whether to customize `NSTableView`, `NSTableRowView`, `NSTableCellView` or `NSSegmentedControl`. I've tried to understand how `refuseFirstResponder` works as well. Trial and error is not getting me anywhere - I fix something and break something somwehre else. If someone can suggest any other reading besides Apple documentation (sometimes I suspect if it is in English) would really appreciate it.

Comment: Use `NSTableViewDelegate` method `selectionShouldChange(in:)`.

Comment: Yes I have done that. Here is my problem.

Comment: Yes, I have done that and works perfectly if all I have is NSTextFields in my cells. I trap that notification and prompt user if current selected row should be saved. Problem is the moment I add another control such as NSSegmentControl, and user clicks in that column in another row, I do not get the `selectionShouldChange` notification. So I need to prevent user from selecting another row until I'm done with my NSSegmentControl - i.e. until I stop editing my row - only "editing" is not like text field editing but selecting my segments

Comment: Wait a second, I should have read carefully. I see now what Willeke is saying. However, to prevent selection from changing, how do I detect my NSSegmentControl has the "focus" and is still being "edited"? I'm thinking I can use tableView.selectedRow to get rowView then navigate to the NSSegmentControl. Then what? And even then still unsure how to prevent click in the other row in the segment control

Comment: So only the selected row can be edited and the row must be valid before selecting another row? When the user clicks on a control in another row, should the control handle the click or should the row be selected first and the next click handled by the control?

Comment: So to state it simply, I need to change the definition of what it means to "edit" a row beyond NSTextField, and onto other controls in my table cells. Thanks to this and other posts I was able to figure it out (while I do have a question). I subclassed NSSegmentedControl. Implemented keyDown() to simply eat up Up/Down arrows. Implemented mouseDown() - navigated up the view hierarchy to find the tableView, then ate up event IFF selectedRow is not the same as view(for: mySegmentedControl). Now how do bootstrap my customization by disabling a property "allowSelectionDuringEditing" in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Subclass `NSTableRowView` and override `hitTest(_:)`. If the row is not selected then the row view returns itself instead of a control. The first click in a row selects the row and doesn't change the value of a control.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    let view = super.hitTest(point)
    if view == nil || self.isSelected {
        return view
    }
    else {
        return self
    }
}
```

Implement `NSTableViewDelegate`'s `tableView(_:rowViewForRow:)` to use the custom row view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
    return MyTableRowView()
}
```

Implement `NSTableViewDelegate`'s `selectionShouldChange(in:)` so a row can't be deselected if the values aren't valid or other conditions aren't met.

```
func selectionShouldChange(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Bool {
    let row = tableView.selectedRow
    if (row >= 0) {
        return self.validateRow(row)
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if you saw my comment above. I was able to get past my problem by subclassing NSSegmentedControl. Thought it is good solution to since code changes contained within the control implementation and of course if my subclassed control does not lie within a tableView then none of my code executes. I did try doing what you said with subclassing NSTableRowView, but I had trouble getting it to work because I didn't know at the time the trick to use correct identifier for IB to use it. I will surely look into it.